# Remotely turn on location for lost/stolen phone

Tags: gps, geolocation, remote-control, lost-phone, location-services

My Samsung Galaxy S7 was lost or stolen tonight at an airport.  I can remotely see that it is at 63% battery power, but I had the Google location turned off.

How can I remotely turn on the location?  (I did lock the phone because I didn't password-protect it and left a message to call my husband.)

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't

Answer (score 1):

Uhm... As far as I know, there is no possibility to remotely turn on GPS on your lost/stolen phone unfortunately, which is why I always considered this "track my phone" Google feature absolutely useless.

Comment: What functionality you used to check your phone battery level?

Comment: search for "find my phone"